# Error in developing magento 2.2 theme (Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): ...)

Tags: theme, magento2.2.2, parent-child-theme, custom-theme

**config:
php 7.0.22**

**mamp 4.2**

**Magento-2.2.2 without sample data**

**localhost running.**

Hello! 
Currently I'm trying to learn how to develop a custom theme for magento, i followed the following steps :  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

My theme folder structure:

magento/app/design/frontend/**Guilherme/guitheme/** ---> root dir

**guitheme/composer.json**

```
{
 "name": "Guilherme/guitheme",
 "description": "guitheme",
 "require": {
   "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
   "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
   "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
 },
 "type": "magento2-theme",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "license": ["OSL-3.0","AFL-3.0" ],
 "autoload": {
   "files": [
     "registration.php"]} }
```

**guitheme/etc/view.xml**

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image"><width>240</width<height>300</height></image>
```

**guitheme/registration.php**

```
<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
   'frontend/Guilherme/guitheme',
   __DIR__
   );
   ?>
```

**guitheme/theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
        <title>guitheme</title>
        <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
        <media>
            <preview_image>media/logoimage.jpg</preview_image>
        </media>
</theme>
```

after that, i run the CLI command: setup:upgrade
and i receive the following error:

**Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Specification mandate value for attribute n in Entity, line: 3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Theme.php on line 75**

and i cant acess my localhost/magento/admin page anymore, but if i remove my created theme i can.

someone have any ideia?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the process described - https://rishabhrkrai.wordpress.com/2018/01/02/magento-2-create-customchild-theme/

Comment: i receive the same error in the CLI described before after i do all of the steps.

Comment: Which command you run on CLI?

Comment: cache:clean after that setup:static-content:deploy